# Slow to open 'viewPanel' (Xpages)

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I'm having a sloppy problem loading a viewPanel, the page opens but it looks like the data source is loading all the documents at once, at that point trying to open a listed document takes a long time. Can you tell me if you can limit the amount of documents loaded by data source? to improve performance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoView var="viewProposta" keysExactMatch="true"
        dataCache="nodata">

        <xp:this.categoryFilter><![CDATA[#{javascript:var filtro=[];
                if(viewScope.statusVoltar!=null){
                    viewScope.status=viewScope.statusVoltar;
                    sessionScope.remove("statusVoltar");
                } 
                if(compositeData.filtraUsuario){
                    filtro.push(sessionScope.usuarioLogado.nome);
                }
                if(compositeData.filtraEntidade){
                    filtro.push(sessionScope.usuarioLogado.fk_entidade_funcional);
                }
                return filtro.join("\\");}]]>
        </xp:this.categoryFilter>

        <xp:this.viewName><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(!viewScope.minhasPendencias ){   
            if(compositeData.filtraEntidade){
                switch(viewScope.status) {
                    case "Solicitado":
                        var vw = "vw_parecer_solicitado_entidade"
                        break;
                    ...
                }
            }
            if(compositeData.filtraUsuario){
                switch(viewScope.status) {
                    case "Solicitado":
                        var vw = "vw_parecer_solicitado_usuario"
                        break;
                    ....
                    }
                }
            }else
            var vw= "vw_parecer_minhas_pendencias";

            return vw;}]]>
        </xp:this.viewName>
    </xp:dominoView>

</xp:this.data>


<xp:viewPanel value="#{viewProposta}" rows="20" id="viewPanel1"
    pageName="/xsp_parecer.xsp" viewStyleClass="bloco" var="doc">

    <xp:viewColumn columnName="ds_status" id="viewColumn8"
        style="">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:viewColumnHeader value="" xp:key="header"
                id="viewColumnHeader8" style="text-align:center">
            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:this.facets>
        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.statusVector.length>0}]]></xp:this.rendered>
    </xp:viewColumn>


    <xp:viewColumn columnName="ds_parecer" displayAs="link"
        style="width:18.0%">
        <xp:this.openDocAsReadonly><![CDATA[#{javascript:var valores:java.util.Vector =doc.getDocument().getItemValue("no_destinatarios");
            valores.addAll(doc.getDocument().getItemValue("no_emitente"));
            return !valores.contains(sessionScope.usuarioLogado.nome);}]]></xp:this.openDocAsReadonly>
        <xp:viewColumnHeader style="text-align:center"
            value="Ds_parecer">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>

        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xp:actionGroup>
                    <xp:executeScript>
                        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(compositeData.filtraEntidade)
                                return sessionScope.retornarPara="/xsp_lista_propostas_unidade.xsp";
                            else
                                return sessionScope.retornarPara="/xsp_lista_propostas.xsp";}]]>
                        </xp:this.script>
                    </xp:executeScript>
                    <xp:openPage target="editDocument"
                        documentId="#{javascript:doc.getDocument().getUniversalID()}">
                        <xp:this.name><![CDATA[#{javascript:return "/xsp_"+doc.getDocument().getItemValueString("form").split("_")[1]+".xsp"}]]></xp:this.name>
                    </xp:openPage>
                </xp:actionGroup>
            </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>

    </xp:viewColumn>

    <xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn2" style="width:13%">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        if(!doc.isCategory()){
            var fk=doc.getDocument().getItemValueString("fk_proposta");
            if(fk == null || fk == "")
                fk = doc.getDocument().getItemValueString("fk_proposta_aux");
            return @DbLookup("","vw_proposta_pesquisa",fk,"ds_proposta");}}]]></xp:this.value>
        <xp:viewColumnHeader id="viewColumnHeader2" value="Proposta"
            style="text-align:center">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>

    <xp:viewColumn columnName="no_processo_adm" id="viewColumn10"
        style="">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:viewColumnHeader value="No_processo_adm"
                xp:key="header" id="viewColumnHeader10"
                style="text-align:center">
            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:this.facets>
    </xp:viewColumn>

    <xp:viewColumn columnName="ds_assunto">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Ds_assunto" xp:key="header"
                style="text-align:center">
            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:this.facets>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="unidade_solicitante"
        style="width:8%">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Unidade_solicitante"
            style="text-align:center">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="no_remetente" id="viewColumn4"
        style="text-align:left">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="No_remetente"
            id="viewColumnHeader4" style="text-align:center">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>

    <xp:viewColumn columnName="ct_posicao_parecer" id="viewColumn3"
        styleClass="centro">

        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.status=="Concluído"}]]></xp:this.rendered>
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Ct_posicao_parecer"
            id="viewColumnHeader3" style="text-align:center">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>

    <xp:viewColumn columnName="dt_envio" id="viewColumn5"
        styleClass="centro">
        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.status!="Concluído"}]]></xp:this.rendered>
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Dt_envio" id="viewColumnHeader5"
            style="text-align:center">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>

    <xp:viewColumn columnName="dt_conclusao" id="viewColumn1"
        styleClass="centro">

        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.status=="Concluído"}]]></xp:this.rendered>
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Dt_conclusao"
            id="viewColumnHeader1" style="text-align:center">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>

    <xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn7" rendered="false">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return ""}]]></xp:this.value>
        <xp:button value="Remover" id="killdoc">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="partial" refreshId="viewPanel1" id="eventHandler1">

                <xp:this.script>
                    <xp:executeClientScript>
                        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[return window.confirm("Confirma a exclusão?")]]></xp:this.script>
                    </xp:executeClientScript>
                </xp:this.script>

                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var d:NotesDocument=doc.getDocument();
                    apagarProposta(d);}]]>
                </xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="" id="viewColumnHeader7"
            rendered="false">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" xp:key="headerPager"
            id="pager1" rendered="true" layout="Previous Group Next">
        </xp:pager>
        <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next"
            xp:key="footerPager" id="pager2">
        </xp:pager>

    </xp:this.facets>
</xp:viewPanel>
```

Comment: are you able to share a code snippet of what you have at the moment?

Comment: I notice you use `dataCache="nodata"` which instruct the page to rebuild the view data from scratch whenever a new POST operation occurs - likely this the culprit of your poor performance when going to open a listed document, or at least the reason why it's as slow as loading the view for the first time, granted I understood you correctly. Any particular reason why `nodata`?

Comment: @shillem i do not know the real reason, the configuration was already this way. But I imagine this is influencing the loading of documents. Can you tell me if loading a view with more than a thousand documents will load everything at the moment the view is accessed?
If changing this cache setting can performance improve?

Comment: What IBM Domino version are you running and what application xsp properties have you set?

Comment: @shillem version 8.5.3
Xsp properties:
xsp.ajax.renderwholetree=true
xsp.application.forcefullrefresh=true
xsp.application.timeout=90
xsp.compress.mode=gzip-nolength
xsp.error.page=error.xsp
xsp.error.page.default=true
xsp.library.depends=com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library
xsp.min.version=8.5.3
xsp.partial.update.timeout=120
xsp.persistence.mode=basic
xsp.persistence.tree.maxviews=16
xsp.redirect=false
xsp.resources.aggregate=true
xsp.session.timeout=90
xsp.theme=titlePages.theme
xsp.theme.mobile.pagePrefix=m_

Comment: The one you have is a lethal combination: you're working with a categorized view on a pre 9.0.1 Domino version. Besides your use of code that should be discouraged you have a performance problem acknowledged and fixed by IBM in 9.0.1. Quicker fix would be to upgrade to Domino 9.0.1 and then kick performances again by adding `xsp.domino.view.navigator=ByNoteId` to your properties. But until 9.0.1, no gain.

Answer (score 4):

You have some very "expensive" things in your viewPanel like

- @DbLookup
- doc.getDocument().getItemValueString(...)
- doc.getDocument().getItemValue(...)

Try to get rid of them.

It is a performance killer if you access fields in underlaying document(s). It is way better, to include all needed data in view columns.

Even worse is @DbLookup. It executes a call to another view for every row in the view. Try to call @DbLookup from a button or on mouseover only.

Answer (score 0):

The number of documents loaded depends on the number of rows defined. The ViewNavigator functionality is optimised to only display the ones for the current page plus some more.

The exception to that is if a Pager has `alwaysCalculateLast` set to `true`. If so, it needs to iterate through the whole view in order to work out the page number it needs to display as the last.

Comment: In case this property is empty. would it be interesting to mark false?

Comment: No, false is the default